# Cannot print period ('.') from simple AppleScript to VMware Fusion virtual machine

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, vmware, services

So I have a simple AppleScript that I think should type a bunch of keys, but the period character doesn't print in VMware Fusion's virtual machines. This is odd because my period key (<kbd>.</kbd>) enters a period like normal in those VMs.

## MCVE

Here is my latest version that I tried:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set file_text to "this another test: ... hello ..."
    delay 0.3
    repeat with ch in file_text
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke ch
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    return input
end run
```

I built this as a service in Automator. I run this by going to my application, then in the Title bar I select Services -> quicktype.

## Expected Behavior

It should just type the text `this another test: ... hello ...`. In many application, it does exactly that.

## True Behavior

In a FreeBSD VM, pressing <kbd>.</kbd> renders a period at the shell (like normal). When the above script runs, however, the periods look like backspaces. End result:
[image: FreeBSD after running script]

In a Windows VM, <kbd>.</kbd> renders a period in Notepad (like normal). When the above script runs, however, the periods seem to be ignored completely. End result:
[image: Windows Notepad after running script]

## Questions

Is there a way to **truly** emulate pressing the keys from a string of characters in AppleScript? Because clearly the above way isn't doing that.

Does anyone know why the behavior I described above is happening? Why does this work in TextMate and Terminal, and other mac apps, but not in Fusion VMs?

Comment: If by chance something, somewhere in the VM is changing the three consecutive periods:

   . . .
into an ellipsis:
    ...



it would explain the backspace behavior in the BSD shell. Try two periods instead of three, or separate them with spaces. (As it happens, I had to separate the three periods in this post with spaces to prevent them from turning into an ellipsis.)

Comment: @DocG. I did already; I used a bunch of different test strings. My original string was `u = Address.first`. I used `vim` to write everything so it wasn't converting anything like some word processors do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why this isn't working, however I do have a fix. I figured out that doing `tell application "System Events" to key code 47` sends a period correctly.

So, I wrapped my read into a conditional like this:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    #set input_file to "/path/to/file"
    #set file_text to read input_file
    set file_text to "test: ... hello ..."
    delay 0.3
    repeat with ch in file_text
        if ch as string = "." then
            tell application "System Events" to key code 47
        else
            tell application "System Events" to keystroke ch
        end if
        delay 0.1
    end repeat

    return input
end run
```